# How can I get event for re-active chrome extension's service worker?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I am developing one Chrome extension with `Manifest V3` and I am stuck on one scenario.

I am using one local variable that is assign from sync storage when storage is change, and based on that variable's value, I am updating my UI, But when `serviceWorker` re-active after sleep some time. My variable's value is reassign to default and it breaks my UI.

I want to catch some event from Chrome before active service worker again so that I can assign my local variable again from sync storage.

***service-worker.js***:

```
var ShowCount = true;  // default value is true

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
  for (let [key, { oldValue, newValue }] of Object.entries(changes)) {
    if (key == "showCount") {
      // newValue is boolean
      ShowCount = newValue
    }
  }
});
```

=> on `showCount` (through switch control) toggle: update sync storage with new value and event listener on it will update my local variable.

If my variable's value is false make by user. Then it will reassign to true as default value when service worker is again active after some time.

Is there any Chrome event that is fired when service worker is again active?

I tried `chrome.idle` but that is not firing on active/idle state change of service worker.

Comment: You don't need an event for that. The entire script runs each time it re-activates so simply add the code at the start of the script.

Comment: Thanks For help buddy. It's now working. I removed that local variable and used sync storage and getting every time from there.